# Phalcon cannot find controller. Error 404 Not found

Tags: php, wamp, phalcon

I started with a phalcon project and used this tutorial (https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/tutorial-base#basic). But i've got a problem with my controllers.

In my index controller i have:

```php
echo $this->tag->linkTo(
    'signup',
    'Sign Up Here!'
);
```

But when i click on Sign Up Here! i get the error message "The requested URL /signup was not found on this server."

I think it has something to do with this part of code, but it looks correct to me.

```php
$di->set(
    'url',
    function () {
        $url = new UrlProvider();
        $url->setBaseUri('/');
        return $url;
    }
);
```

It's not even showing my exception

```
$application = new Application($di);

try {
    // Handle the request
    $response = $application->handle();

    $response->send();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception: ', $e->getMessage();
}
```

I followed the tutorial on youtube as well and did everything in exact the same way as he did in the video. So i was wondering if anyone can help me out here.

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNRcD.png)

Thanks

Comment: The message is pretty clear - most likely there is no `SignupController.php` file. Judging by what I read in the same tutorial this seems to be true. Pay attantion to the file structure in tutorial. Also Routing might be configured incorrectly.

Comment: I do have a SignupController.php and im pretty sure my file structure is correct too. I've added an image of my file structure

Comment: Did you setup router? Could you amend your question by providing relevant part of the router as well as web server virtual host configuration?

Comment: If the routing here is anything similar to Zend Routing, then I agree - the most likely problem at this point is the router. When you click the link, looks like you get routed to `/` (baseUri), which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the main .htaccess file in the public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And this could be the reason why the exception is not being generated.